# PHP regex multiline one part of string

Tags: php, regex, dom, multiline

I want to have One part multiline in a regex

```
<?php
 function bloggerLoop ( $matches ) { print_r ( $matches ) ; }

 $theme = preg_replace_callback(
         "#<b:loop values='data:(.*)' var='(.*)'>(.*?)</b:loop>#i",
         "bloggerLoop", 
         $theme 
         );
?>
```

This is what I have, but `b:loop` is more than once in the template and this regex skips all the loops and make one "big" loop, but i only need to have one "part".

What need is:

```
<b:loop values='data:x' var='x'>MULTILINE</b:loop>
```

The file what is needed to be parsed is: http://pastebin.com/a3g3G1uE

I hope you can help me with the regex.

Tanks.

-Wesley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is not the tool for this. HTML tag structure is too complex, for basic Regex, and you should try some HTML DOM library like [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), to do HTML DOM work.

```
$html = file_get_html('http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=a3g3G1uE');
foreach($html->find('b:loop') as $element)
       echo $element->values. '<br>';
```

Look at my [example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/G8PMHr) for your specific case and read [documentation](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm).